# POST method not allowed in custom viewsets

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-2.7, django-models, django-rest-framework

if I am going to add products to cart I get error. POST method not allowed

**views.py**

```
class CartViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Cart.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CartSerializer


@action(methods=['post', 'put'], detail=False)
def add_to_cart(self, request, pk=None):

    cart = self.get_object()
    try:
        cart.user = self.request.user
        product = Product.objects.get(pk=request.data['product'])
        quantity = int(request.data['quantity'])
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return Response({'status': 'fail'})

    if product.inventory <= 0 or product.inventory - quantity < 0:
        print('There is no inventory in store')

        return Response({'status': 'fail'})

    existing_cart_item = CartItem.objects.filter(cart=cart, product=product).first()

    if existing_cart_item:
        existing_cart_item.quantity += quantity
        existing_cart_item.save()

    else:
        new_cart_item = CartItem(cart=cart, product=product, quantity=quantity)
        new_cart_item.save()

    serializer = CartSerializer(cart)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

**urls.py**

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'carts', CartViewSet)
router.register(r'cart_items', CartItemViewSet)



urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

It works when i give the url like that `carts/1/add_to_cart` here I am giving my cart id but in my case it is wrong because when user is created cart is also created that's why user and cart ids are same. I do not nedd to give cart id in the url because I am putting token in Authorization section in Postman, from that it should detect which user is sending post request.  It is shown above that I added `cart.user=self.request.user` with it still it is not working. How can I solve this issue? Any help would be appreciated)

Comment: include your urls where you register your views. I have a feeling the issue will be there

Comment: @EnthusiastMartin please have a look at updated version

Comment: Ah, ok. now I understand what you want to do. It has nothing to do with post method not allowed.  If in understand correcty, you want to add item to user's cart (and dont want to have url with cart id ), right ?

Comment: @EnthusiastMartin yes i is right

Answer (score 0):

So your problem is not "post method not allowed"

You want to do something like this:

```
[POST,PUT] carts/add_to_cart
```

and this should add items to user's cart.

I think that the ModelViewSet is not really good view choice for this operation ( in the way you want to do it ).

I would create a new view to handle this instead, and leave the viewset to handle Cart operations.

So, delete add_to_cart method from your view.

You can create view like this:

```
class CartUpdateView(generics.UpdateAPIView):

    queryset = None
    serializer_class = CartUpdateSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user.cart
```

Register this view for your endpoint ( even though  i would structure the endpoints differently ):

```
path("cart/add_to_cart", CartUpdateView.as_view())
```

And create `CartUpdateSerializer` to add the items to the cart ( like you did in the add_to_cart but in will be in the serializer instead).

And don't rely on Cart and User having same ids even if you create them at the same. It is not guaranteed.

Comment: thank you for answer. but If i delete `add_to_cart` method how can I add items?

Comment: You move the implementation to the serializer's update method. Serializer is the place where such things should be done anyway.  You will have access to the cart instance and validated data which you pass when doing put request. If you include your models, i can add example of such serializer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! but this did not work for me. I uploaded new question related to this please can you have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58462090/drf-saving-objects-in-database